# How can I eliminate some areas by attribute from a shapefile in R and create a new shapefile?

Tags: r, subset, arcgis, shapefile

I have been at this for a while now and have had some success, however when it comes to rewriting the file, I have had none.

The shapefile I am working with is a polygon shapefile of metro and micropolitan areas but I am not interested in the micropolitan areas so I am working with the shp in R to try and eliminate them from my map.

[Data Source](http://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles2010/layers.cgi)

To download the right file, make sure that you select "All States in one national file" under "Metropolitan/Micropolitan Statistical Area (2010)"

Here's what I have so far:

```
library(maptools)
met=readShapeSpatial("tl_2010_us_cbsa10.shp")
met=met@data
```

Before subset:

```
NAMELSAD10      LSAD10
Anchorage, AK Metro Area   -  M1 
Clarksdale, MS Micro Area    - M2
Richmond, VA Metro Area   -  M1
Big Spring, TX Micro Area  -   M2
Dallas-Fort Worth-Arlington, TX Metro Area  -   M1
Rio Grande City-Roma, TX Micro Area  -   M2
```

then:

```
submet=subset(met, LSAD10 == "M1")
```

After subset:

```
NAMELSAD10 LSAD10
Anchorage, AK Metro Area   -  M1
Richmond, VA Metro Area  -   M1
Dallas-Fort Worth-Arlington, TX Metro Area   -  M1
Vineland-Millville-Bridgeton, NJ Metro Area  -   M1
Casper, WY Metro Area   -  M1
Cheyenne, WY Metro Area   -  M1
```

then:

```
writeSpatialShape(submet, "tl_2010_us_ma10", factor2char = TRUE)
```

Using this code I have been able to successfully eliminate the Micropolitan areas designated "M1" but when I try to rewrite the file, it doesn't show up in my wd.

I have also attempted using the package "shapefiles" to get this done but had even less success. So any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your link to the data goes nowhere.

Comment: You can demonstrate to us that it's not in your "wd" by running list.files(".") and posting that too. I just don't believe it's not there, I reckon you've mistaken your "wd" with R's current directory.

Comment: Ok I take that back, Spacedman has demonstrated it. :)

Comment: And I've now reported the behaviour to the maptools maintainer!

Comment: And Roger has added an error message and will release a new version to CRAN soon. Dontcha LOVE open source?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you do `met=met@data` you are losing the Spatial aspect of `met` and just getting the plain old data frame.

Then you subset that data frame okay, and then you try and `writeSpatialShape` it. Whoa. The `submet` object doesn't have any polygons or coordinates. `writeSpatialShape` should barf. But it manages to swallow it whole and keep it down. Check this out:

```
> writeSpatialShape(1,"foo.shp")
>
```

and as you observed, no shapefile is created. Wow, that's pretty sucky error handling.

Two solutions: 1, work on the actual object rather than the data component, like this:

```
met = readOGR(dir,name)
submet = met[met$thing=="whatever",]
writeOGR(submet,dir,newname,"ESRI Shapefile")
```

2, use `package:rgdal` and `read/write|OGR` which not only handles projections but is violently sick if you try and make it eat something unpalatable:

```
> writeOGR(1,".","foo","ESRI Shapefile")
Error: inherits(obj, "Spatial") is not TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, and for your help. I followed your second recommendation and used rgdal instead and got my desired results. I even got my new shapefile opened in ArcGIS and it is perfect.